# position: fixed; breaking my web page

Tags: html, css

***Code:***

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-logo"><a href="#">Wanye Kest Designs</a></div>
            <nav class="header-nav">
                <a href="#">Work</a>
                <a href="#">Conatact</a>
            </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="pagess">Pages will go here</div>
</body>
```

***///////////////////////////////////////***
***CSS:***

```
body {
    background-color: #f3efed;
    font-family: "arial", sans-serif;
    color: #8e4e13;
    margin: 0;
}
.header-logo a {
    color: #8e4e13;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header-logo {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 28px;
}
.header {
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.header-nav {
    float: right;
}
.header-logo {
    float: left;
}
.header-nav a { 
    color: #C3A286; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    line-height: 28px;
}
```

With this code, Nav links and header logo are one the same verticle alignment, opposite sides of page, and a text "Pages will be here" is positioned below the header logo perfectly.

My issue is that as soon as I enter ***position: fixed;*** below the ***.header*** selector, the Navigation links re-position themselves to overlap the header logo on the left side of the page, and the "Pages will be here" text re-positions itself above the header.

Please understand I'm extremely new to web design (HTML, CSS, JS, etc...) and the training program I refer to doesn't have a trouble-shooting section, videos or a forum (HACKSAW Academy).

Can someone Identify the problem? I'm typing the code exactly as it tells me and can't find a workaround.

[without ***position: fixed;***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHPhR.png)

[With ***position: fixed;***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfMOr.png)

Comment: An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used to position the element.     
A fixed element does not leave a gap in the page where it would normally have been located.  [link]http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Position: fixed;` takes the element out of the normal flow of the document, so that is where the overlap is coming from. By default, this moves all the elements to the top left. Also, `float` is superseded by `position: fixed`, as `float` is in the flow of the document while again `position: fixed` is not. The only remaining element not `position: fixed` is your `pagess` class, which rightly takes up the top-left spot in the flow of the document.

Here's something you can work with:

```css
*, :before, :after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #f3efed;
    font-family: "arial", sans-serif;
    color: #8e4e13;
    margin: 0;
}
.header-logo a {
    color: #8e4e13;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header-logo {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 28px;
}
.header {
    padding: 15px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
}
.header-nav {
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-left: calc(55% - 100px);
}
.header-logo {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.header-nav a { 
    color: #C3A286; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    line-height: 28px;
}

.pagess {
    margin-top: 48px;
    margin-left: 24px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-logo"><a href="#">Wanye Kest Designs</a></div>
        <nav class="header-nav">
          <a href="#">Work</a>
          <a href="#">Conatact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="pagess">Pages will go here</div>
</body>
```

Comment: So, do I do position: fixed; on the pagess class? That would remove it from the document flow. All I can seem to understand is that currently everything that isn't the header will show up above the header so that the header is on the bottom of the page.

Comment: It's fine to do `position:fixed` on just the navigation bar, with the `pagess` class in the normal document flow. Just make sure to add a margin-top, which is already added for you in the snippet. **Edit**: once you have set elements to `position: fixed`, you have to declare an X and Y coordinate for it (e.g., `left: 0`, `top: 0`). Otherwise it may do some weird things such as attach itself to the nearest element in the document flow.

Comment: By the way, if the answer I posted has answered your question, please do upvote and accept it! Hope it helps.